# Install custom Outlook 2003 form in users Personal Form Library programmatically

Tags: forms, outlook, publish

We've a customer Outlook 2003 form and it is published to the Organisational Form Library on the Exchange Server. But the newest version of Exchange Server will not support Organisational Form Libary for our Outlook 2003 form.

We need a way to publish this form in the user's Personal Form Library to reuse. Is it possible to distribute the Outlook 2003 form programmatically? We don't want that the user should configure it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Outlook 2003 would even be able to connect to Exchange 2016. You will need Outlook 2010 SP3 or newer for that.

Microsoft had been deprecating forms for a long time - your best option is a COM addin that supports a form region or a task pane.

As for installing forms, your only option is Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) and the [IMAPIFormContainer::InstallForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815785(v=office.12).aspx) function that takes the name of the CFG file.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it explicitly exposes the [RDOMAPIFormContainer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMAPIFormContainer.htm) object and the `InstallForm` method (takes the file name of the CFG file).

Comment: Thanks. I means, we use outlook 2003 form (.opt), not Outlook 2003 application. This format (.opt) will be supported in other outlook versions.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented a new COM addin to intall the form. I think it is the easy way.

Comment: You can also use Redemption for that - see the updated answer above.